# Write-but-not-delete permissions on SAMBA

Tags: permissions, samba, share, accounts

I installed samba on my linux server for public file sharing on the LAN. I works great currently, but I would like to add some security:

People from LAN should be able to Read files present and Add new ones, but not delete files. I want to keep this privilege for me ;-)

How should-I do this? I have set up a "admin" account having full access even to deletion. There is just left to configure the "guest" acount. Google isn't helping that much right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the smb.conf manual page and search for

inherit owner = yes